# Hiding gridview column and get it when clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to learn using jquery with asp.net and I have a gridview. I want to hide userId in gridview but getting Id value of clicked row. Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="addGridControl" CssClass="mGrid"  PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CustomerId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" SortExpression="CompanyName"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" SortExpression="ContactName"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactTitle" HeaderText="ContactTitle" SortExpression="ContactTitle"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="Region"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fax" HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my jquery attempt:

```
$("#addGridControl tr").click(function () {
        var secilen = $(this).closest('tr').find("#Label1").attr("Text");
        alert(secilen);
    });
```

I am sure you can see that it is not working in the first look. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace:

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
```

By

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="notVisible" ItemStyle-CssClass="notVisible" FooterStyle-CssClass="notVisible">
```

With the class style:

```
.notVisible
{
    display: none;
}
```

When the `Visible` property is set to `false`, ASP.NET removes the control from the HTML output. Consequently, the client code will not find it.